# Vagrant Config Error - “A box must be specified.”

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

My configuration is below and the boxes were working fine:

---

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  (1..4).each do |i|

    config.vm.define "node#{i}", autostart:true do |node|

        config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
        config.vm.hostname="node#{i}"
        config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.59.#{i}"
        config.vm.synced_folder "~/Documents/csunp/unp", "/vagrant/unp"
        config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
            v.name = "node#{i}"
            v.memory = 512
            v.cpus = 1
        end
    end
  end
end
```

---

But once I power down my computer, I can't go back any more.
Running `vagrant up`, I got the error below:

```
Bringing machine 'node1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'node2' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'node3' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'node4' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* A box must be specified.
```

What's wrong with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hum your Vagrantfile is not very well written, you created a loop to create 4 instances with a node variable but still uses config.vm

If you want to keep simple, change to

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  (1..4).each do |i|

    config.vm.define "node#{i}", autostart:true do |node|

        node.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
        node.vm.hostname="node#{i}"
        node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.59.#{i}"
        node.vm.synced_folder "~/Documents/csunp/unp", "/vagrant/unp"
        node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
            v.name = "node#{i}"
            v.memory = 512
            v.cpus = 1
        end
    end
  end
end
```

If you're using the same box for all 4 VMs, you can write as

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.synced_folder "~/Documents/csunp/unp", "/vagrant/unp"

  (1..4).each do |i|

    config.vm.define "node#{i}", autostart:true do |node|

        node.vm.hostname="node#{i}"
        node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.59.#{i}"
        node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
            v.name = "node#{i}"
            v.memory = 512
            v.cpus = 1
        end
    end
  end
end
```